'cd' command not working on osx anymore
I am using terminal on my osx with zsh, and it is the same for vscode. But since this Monday I am unable to use cd command, and also in vscode terminal ng specific commands. I checked everything and I have the latest running version of everything, and I just cannot figure out alone what is the issue... I tried out almost everything I found on stackoverflow and with google but nothing solved my issue. Any ides maybe? It is really absurd that I can create, list, delete stuff but cannot enter into it :s ...
I tried out checking my config, adding stuff to path, trying brew doctor to see if anything went aside, checking proper ng version is running, and if i use proper config file for my bash. Even tried what it returns as type for cd.
For example cd Web or cd ./Web worked before, no it is not... With ls command I can see it there, can create new files and folders inside it and remove them, but cannot enter inside it or them with the CD command...
screenshot of the terminal after commands like pwd, ls-l, and cd

$ type -a cd 
cd is an alias for cd(); enter_directory 
cd is a shell function 
cd is a shell builtin 
cd is /usr/bin/cd 


So... what happens? Is here an error? Try this: pwd; ls -l; cd SomeDirectory; pwd. cut and paste from your terminal and add it to your question. "Does not work" is a useless problem description.

@glennjackman Sorry, I updated the OQ with a screenshot where everything is visible.

Edit your post., type <hr> and a linefeed - i.e. hit Enter - then add the output of $ type -a cd

Try builtin cd Web.

@Hannu
➜  ~ type -a cd
cd is an alias for cd(); enter_directory
cd is a shell function
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd

@Gairfowlwow with this works.. but what is builtin? Also how can I make it to work like it again?

Something in one of your shell init files is defining a nonsensical alias for cd. You'll need to find and remove (or fix) that alias definition, and maybe other bad changes that were made around monday.

@CreativeZoller I have added the text to the question in the manner that I wanted YOU to do. Please do it like that in any coming Q's.

Exactly as @GordonDavisson says:
Something in one of your shell init files is defining a nonsensical alias for cd. You'll need to find and remove (or fix) that alias definition, and maybe other bad changes that were made around monday.
Check the contents of the shell initialization files;
for Bash these are e.g. $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.bash_aliases, $HOME/.bash_profile
$ man bash will tell you more.
$ bash --norc  might also start a shell bypassing all those files.
You need to find the corresponding files for zsh
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108136/78842 might give some useful hints.

Thank you for this detailed comment. I tried out stuff and checked the profiles but saw nothing extra. And then run the newuser-install command from the URL you shared and somehow it immediately works again both in the terminal and vscode... tried out a lot of commands, and cd now again works. Thank you!
